Typescript, React: Spread Operator vs Spread Operator with Bracketed Object?
What is the difference between this
<Link {...{underline: "hover", style: {...}}}>
this
<Link {...{obj}}>
and this
<Link {...obj}>
?
The obj type is a const {} type:
const obj = { underline: "hover", style: {} }
I confirmed that underline and style are both usable in the Link class.
The last throws an error but it seems like they should all be the same type? Am using MaterialUI Link if that helps.

The first and last are equivalent to <Link underline="hover" style={{}}> while the middle one is equivalent to <Link obj={{ underline: 'hover', style: {} }}>

"The last throws an error" - what's the error message?!

@Bergi "No overload matches this call", missing property 'component'. Overload 2: "underline" incompatible because "string" type not assignable to type "none"|"hover"|...

Then you'll need const obj = { underline: "hover" as const, ….

If you have a variable named obj, then {obj} is a shorthand way of writing {obj: obj}: it creates an object with a single property named obj whose value is the value of obj. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer for more information — search in that page for "shorthand property names".)
The JSX spread syntax:
<Link {...obj}>

passes the properties of obj as properties of the Link component.
In your case, obj is { underline: "hover", style: {...} }, so the above is equivalent to:
<Link underline="hover" style={obj.style}>

By contrast, this:
<Link {...{obj}}>

is equivalent to this:
<Link {...{obj: obj}}>

which is equivalent to this:
<Link obj={obj}>

which is probably not what you want!
